# Python 2.7 Find occurences from datetime and plot

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot, find-occurrences

Since I didn't find anywhere else this topic I will  ask it here. I am getting data from CSV file, I have written datetime format in one of columns. I get that column with pandas module and then I need to count occurrences in specific time slots and plot that with matplotlib. Bellow you can  see example of column.

```
     Time and Date
0    2015-08-21 10:51:06.398000  
1    2015-08-21 10:51:00.017000  
2    2015-08-21 10:52:06.402000     
3    2015-08-21 10:54:06.407000
...
```

I know how I can split time like so:

```
pd.date_range("10:50", "12:30", freq="1min").time
```

But how can I assign occurrences of my read values from CSV and then plot it? Any advice or direction would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you want as you haven't posted desired output but if I understand you correctly you want to count the number of rows in time intervals of certain length. You can do this by combining `resample` and `len`. To use `resample`, first set the index to `'Time and Date`:

```
df.set_index('Date and Time', drop=False)
```

Note that `drop=False` is only necessary if the data frame has no other columns. 
Then to get the number of rows in each 1-minute interval do

```
counts = df.resample('1min', len).astype(int)
```

If there are multiple dates and you want to sum the counts for each time interval over dates do

```
counts.groupby(lambda ts: ts.time()).sum()
```

Comment: I must say you understand correctly, but when I try to resample  I get and TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex.

Comment: Oh I see what's the matter. The first line should be either `df.set_index('Date and Time', drop=False, inplace=True)` or `df = df.set_index('Date and Time', drop=False)`. Without this `df` is not changed in any way

Comment: This works, but since I need hight granularity on us, resample on us hangs.is There any solutuion for that issue?